# How can I calculate sum of query results in Elixir?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, arithmetic-expressions

I have an `order` table. One of columns of this table is total price.

`Total price` is calculated by adding up all prices of `order_item` and `item_attribute`

When a user deletes an `order_item`, I want to make it delete all of related `item_attribute` to `order_item`. So when it calculates total price, it should deduct price of `order_item` and `item_attribute`.

So to do that I made code like below

```
order_item_total = Repo.one!(from p in Pos8.OrderItem, where: p.order_id == ^order_id, select: sum(p.item_total))
total_item_attributes_price = Repo.one!(from p in Pos8.ItemAttribute, where: p.order_id == ^order_id, select: sum(p.price))

order_total_query = (order_item_total + total_item_attributes_price)

Pos8.Order.changeset(order, %{total: order_total_query})
|> Repo.insert_or_update
```

After delete `order_item` and `item_attribute`, it selects sum of total price of `order_item` and `item_attribute`, which are related to `order_id`. And then input its value to Order database.

However, it triggers `(ArithmeticError) bad argument in arithmetic expression`. Which shows that `order_total_query = (order_item_total + total_item_attributes_price)` is not valid argument in arithmetic expression...

How should I calculate `order_total_query`in correct arithmetic expression?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: print the value of `order_item_total` and `total_item_attributes_price` will help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about using [Repo.aggregate/4](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Repo.html#c:aggregate/4) ?